# Release pipeline does not get populated in Run with options of testcases in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created testplans in VSTS. These are only testcase/workitem defined in vsts not related to any .Net projects.

I have created a Release pipeline and want to assign it to each testcase in test suite/plan.

How can I set release pipeline to each testcase?

Also I want to pass arguments to this release pipeline,how can I pass those arguments?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk - by creating build artifacts,I got the first point resolved.I can select the release pipeline. But how can I pass arguments from run with options?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible :/